# Unable to iterate over an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am testing out the nodejs modules [x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) and [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Following is my code:

```
const Xray = require("x-ray");
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const xray = new Xray();

xray('https://news.ycombinator.com/', 'body@html')((err, result) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(`<body>${result}</body>`);

    const elements = $('body')
        .find('*')
        .filter((i, e) => (
            e.type === 'tag'
        ))
        .map((i, e) => {
            e.foo = {
                id: i
            };
            return e;
        })
        .filter((i, e) => (
            e.foo.id % 2 === 0
        ));

    const elementsArray = elements.toArray();

    console.log('Length of the array is:', elementsArray.length);

    elementsArray.forEach((e) => {
        console.log('I appear to print only once, even though elementsArray has lots of elements');
    });
});
```

Issue here is the the `console.log()` inside the `forEach` loop prints only once - even though the output of the earlier `console.log(elementsArray.length)` is about 369.

[Runkit link to test it out](https://runkit.com/callmekatootie/testing-cheerio-xray)

I checked the type of elementsArray and I get `Array` or `array` as the type. Why then does the loop run only once?

Comment: use elementsArray.each(function(key,value) { console.log('message here ')});

Comment: Are you sure? The console often consolidates repetitions of the same message, with just an occurrence counter next to it.

Comment: @KhanShahrukh Why will I use `key, value` in the iterator - I am iterating over an array right, not an object/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is shown many times, but the console will consolidate (what's in a word) repetitions of the same message into one line with a counter next to it.

If you would change the message to make it unique every time, you'd see the difference.

For instance, if you would use the index in the message:

```
elementsArray.forEach((e,i) => {
    console.log(i); // different message on every iteration
});
```

See the difference with the updated script on [runkit.com](https://runkit.com/trincot/58a963e1295cf90014eec247)